# i'm a beginner in laravel and i have an issue with passing a variable from if to else , very very strange

Tags: php, laravel, oop

Please someone help me :( and sorry for these beginner problem , its really strange , `$stdobj` works completely fine when it is in auth and first elseif , and strange thing is that second elseif has exactly the same code , but retunes laravel error Trying to get property of non-object . but it works in first elseif , why it says it is not an object in the last one !!!

```
$our_user = User::check_if_user_matches($username);

    $stdobj = new \stdClass();
    $stdobj = $our_user['usid'];
    if (\Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {

        $logdata = [];
        $v = new Verta();
        $logdata['logTime'] = $v->formatTime();
        $logdata['logDate'] = $v->formatDate();
        $logdata['logCode'] = '001';
        $logdata['user_id'] = $stdobj->id;
        $logs->insert($logdata);
        return redirect()->intended('home');
    } elseif ($our_user['usname'] == $username) {
        $v = new Verta();
        //$stdobj1 = $our_user['usid'];
        $logdata = [];
        $logdata['logTime'] = $v->formatTime();
        $logdata['logDate'] = $v->formatDate();
        $logdata['logCode'] = '003';
        $logdata['user_id'] = $stdobj->id;
        $logs->insert($logdata);
        return redirect()->intended('login');
    } elseif ($our_user['usname'] != $username) {
        $v = new Verta();
        //$stdobj1 = $our_user['usid'];
        $logdata = [];
        $logdata['logTime'] = $v->formatTime();
        $logdata['logDate'] = $v->formatDate();
        $logdata['logCode'] = '002';
        $logdata['user_id'] = $stdobj->id;
        $logs->insert($logdata);
        return redirect()->intended('login');
    } else {
        return back()->withInput();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `assign` value to your obejct. Add this line at top-

```
$stdobj1 = new \stdClass();
$stdobj1->id = $our_user['usid'];;
```

Comment: no man , it gets it's value from `$stdobj1 = $our_user['usid'];` in if , but the value is null in else

Comment: No man , I need if , i want to know if the username that is inserted is correct or not , and if correct , i want to know what is his/her id

Comment: assigned it, whenever you need, its your own logic. what i am trying to say that you need to assign id to the stdobj1, otherwise you will get this error. So assign id to stdobj1 before access id

Comment: i tried what you said , but it didn't work , i need user id , and that should be checked in if , and if that failed , it goes to else , but the user id in else is null , like i didn't got it , but i got , it is working in if . i used referencing this variable , but still null .

Comment: debug your code, see your logic, the problem is solved what you have asked if do like this, now work with your logic

Comment: sorry for bothering you , i solved that problem , but got another strange one , i edited my question , please read it , help me if you can . what is the problem , why it recognises `$stdobj` in first else if , but it returns an error in the second one , laravel tells Trying to get property of non-object for the second one !! but they are exactly the same , this one really dosn't have anything to do with logic !!

Comment: include the full error please and you should have accept this answer a long ago

Comment: add your full error please, i can't help if you don't co-operate me

Comment: no man i solved it . this is new , the laravel error is : Trying to get property of non-object , non object referes to $stdobj !! just read the updated code and my explanation . i'm very sorry , i'm bothring you . but i don't no what to say to my boss :(( . full . when my password is wrong elseif runs and works fine and insert the data to database but when my username is wrong second elseif kicks in , the codes are exactlly exactlly similar , the same code .

Comment: attach full error, what you see in browser. do you get it?? otherwise solve yourself as it seems you solved yourself previous one

Answer (score 0):

because it can't get the password , when there is no username . and you can find a password and compare it to the one in the database , this way :

```
$passes = \DB::table('users')->pluck('password');

      foreach ($passes as $pass) {
          if(\Hash::check($password, $pass)) {
              $this_user_pass = $pass;
              return view('MainPages.example',['pass' => $this_user_pass]);
          }
      }
```